# What is the purpose of the .git file in a submodule directory?

Tags: git, travis-ci, github-pages, git-submodules, hugo

What is the purpose of the .git file in a submodule directory?

The submodule is mapped to the `public` directory which is build with Hugo. This is pushed to a Github pages site.

When I run `hugo --cleanDestinationDir`

What happens if this gets deleted? Can this be recreated within the build in Travis CI?

Answer (score 1):

The .git file is a gitfile:

> A plain file .git at the root of a working tree that points at the directory that is the real repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary

This file contains

```
gitdir: <path>
```

with the path to the parent .git directory.

> This mechanism is often used for a working tree of a submodule checkout, to allow you in the containing superproject to git checkout a branch that does not have the submodule. The checkout has to remove the entire submodule working tree, without losing the submodule repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout